# Why does my simple backbone view click event not firing?

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

here is my scenario of backbone view

```
var TreeNode = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName : "span",
        className : "ndelem dirnode",
        events : {
            "click" : "selectNode",
        },
        initialize : function() {
            _.bindAll(this, "render", "selectNode");
            $(this.el).append(this.model.get("fname")).attr({
                "data-cid" : this.model.cid
            });

        },
        render : function() {
            this.delegateEvents();
            return this;
        },

        selectNode : function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();

            this.model.set({
                isOpened : true
            });
        }
    });
```

Main view

```
var TreeZone = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $("#nodes"),
        initialize : function() {
            this.collection.bind("add", this.list, this);
        },      
        getHtml : function(elem) {
            var newItem = $("<div/>").append(elem);
            return newItem.html();
            newItem.remove();
        },
        getSelectedItem : function() {
            var selectedItem = $('#nodes').jqxTree('selectedItem');
            if (selectedItem != null)
                return selectedItem.element;
            else {
                var treeItems = $('#nodes').jqxTree('getItems');
                var firstItem = treeItems[0];
                return firstItem.element;
            }
        },
        list : function(file) {

            var node = new TreeNode({
                model : file
            });
            var newItem = this.getHtml(node.render().el);

            var element = this.getSelectedItem();

            $('#nodes').jqxTree('addTo', {
                html : newItem,
            }, element);
            $('#nodes').jqxTree('expandItem', element); 
        }
    });

var tree = new TreeZone({collection:dircollection});
```

I adding elements to the collection.

but tree node click event not firing. simply I am adding raw html to the tree node because tree doesnt support jquery object. so I am trying   get html from get html function. and giving it to tree.

Comment: If you want to reference a jQuery object for your view you can use `this.$el` rather than doing `$(this.el)`. Is there some where this can be viewed?

Comment: but why select node not firing

Comment: Have you checked that the element of the tree node is in the DOM, has a size, is on the place you expect it and is not covered by any other element?

Comment: We need to see the HTML to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are bound to DOM elements but you end up working with HTML strings. You're doing this:

```
getHtml : function(elem) {
    var newItem = $("<div/>").append(elem);
    return newItem.html();
    newItem.remove();
},

//...
var newItem = this.getHtml(node.render().el);
```

So `getHTML` returns a string and as soon as you convert your `TreeNode`'s `el` (which is a DOM object) to a string, the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) which Back attaches to `el` for event handling is gone: no `delegate`, no events.

I can see a couple options:

1. Dig the node's `<span>` out of `#nodes` after the `addTo` call and use [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) to re-attach it to the `TreeNode` view.
2. Rearrange the structure so that you don't have `TreeNode` at all. If you attach a class to the node `<span>`s then you could let `TreeZone` deal with all the events; for example, if you used `<span class="node">` for the nodes, then `TreeZone` could have this:

   ```
   events: {
       'click .node': 'selectNode'
   }
   ```

   And you'd have a `selectNode` method on `TreeZone` instead of `TreeNode`. You might need to add a `data-id` attribute to the `<span>`s so that you can backtrack from the `<span>` to the model.

Also, note that your `newItem.remove();` in `getHtml` will never be executed.